# How to fill the Date & Time columns of a time serie dataframe with the timestamp index value of the Serie

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have the following dataframe, where the index is a timestamp:

```
                           Date Time  
2018-11-21 09:50:00-08:00  NaN  NaN    
2018-11-21 08:28:00-08:00  NaN  NaN    
2018-11-21 06:34:00-08:00  NaN  NaN    
2018-11-21 04:44:00-08:00  NaN  NaN     
2018-11-21 04:37:00-08:00  NaN  NaN
```

How may I fill the Date and Time columns with the values given by the Timestamp? So I can get this:

```
                           Date        Time  
2018-11-21 09:50:00-08:00  2018-11-21  09:50 AM    
2018-11-21 08:28:00-08:00  2018-11-21  08:28 AM    
2018-11-21 06:34:00-08:00  2018-11-21  06:34 AM    
2018-11-21 04:44:00-08:00  2018-11-21  04:44 AM     
2018-11-21 04:37:00-08:00  2018-11-21  04:37 AM
```

Thanking you in advance for any help or recommendation....Jose

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the date string from the beginning to the first time, convert to datetime, and use the `date` and `time` accessor, with the proper formatters:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df.index.str.extract('(.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'))

df['Date'] = x.date

df['Time'] = x.strftime('%I:%M %p')

>>> df
                                 Date      Time
2018-11-21 09:50:00-08:00  2018-11-21  09:50 AM
2018-11-21 08:28:00-08:00  2018-11-21  08:28 AM
2018-11-21 06:34:00-08:00  2018-11-21  06:34 AM
2018-11-21 04:44:00-08:00  2018-11-21  04:44 AM
2018-11-21 04:37:00-08:00  2018-11-21  04:37 AM
```

Comment: While the first version of your answer worked perfectly:  `df['Date'] = df.index.date
df['Time'] = df.index.time`, I now get an error with your recently edited answer: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`. Please review and comment...